# What is the distinguishing factor between conviction and threat?

Tags: logic, argumentation, rationality, dilemma

**What is the distinguishing factor between conviction and threat?**

I want my friend to restrain from doing an action. I am showing him the bad consequences of the action thus, I am trying to convince him for not doing the action. He can be convinced or may not be depending on how strong my arguments are against doing the action. I can keep showing him stronger arguments until he becomes convinced of not doing the action.

At what level my arguments will be called threats? The question arose in my head because whatever the final decision of my friend, it actually depends on the cost and benefit (i.e. loss and greed) of my friends.

A concrete example (progression of discussion with my friend),

- Don't do that because someone might die with your action - NOT convinced
- Don't do that because many people might die with your action - NOT convinced
- Don't do that because someone will die with your action - NOT convinced
- Don't do that because many people will die with your action - NOT convinced
- Don't do that because your family members might die with your action - NOT convinced
- Don't do that because your family members will die with your action - NOT convinced
- Don't do that because your family members might be killed for your action - NOT convinced
- Don't do that because your family members will be killed for your action - NOT convinced
- Don't do that because you might die with your action - NOT convinced/convinced
- Don't do that because you might will be killed for your action - NOT convinced/convinced
- Don't do that because we might kill you for your action - convinced
- Don't do that because we will kill you for your action - convinced

Regardless the decision, at which point I can say it was a threat to my friend instead of an  argument for conviction? In other word, **when can I say my friend was convinced and when can I say my friend was threatened?**

---

<sup>Note: If I couldn't express my actual question, please help me to make it precise as I am a non native english speaker.</sup>

Comment: The distinguishing factor is your own role in bringing about the threatening consequences. If you are merely making arguments about  risks of bad events that may transpire for reasons beyond your control, it may turn into alarmism at some point, but it will not be a threat. It will be a threat when *you* are promising to take action that helps them transpire.

Comment: @Conifold thats not that much straight forward to me, for example what if I say "our team will kill you" or "my team will kill you" etc. I am not directly involved here but it's kind of confusing thing between terrorizing and warning. I can generate more complex example if I think.

Comment: @Conifold I mean everyone somehow contributes to events directly or indirectly. At which level of my contribution it would be no longer called a warning instead a threat.

Comment: How many grains does it take to make a heap? There is no bright line, but there are heaps, non-heaps and borderline cases, see [sorites paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox). It is the same with your degree of participation in realizing a threat, or any other vague predicate.

Comment: @Conifold thanks. I will look into that paradox.